# Suggested alternative to death penalty

Tags: death-penalty, ngos

> Amnesty opposes the death penalty in all cases without exception – regardless of who is accused, the nature or circumstances of the crime, guilt or innocence or method of execution.
>
> Amnesty International

> The death penalty has no place in the 21st century.
>
> António Guterres'

My question is what alternative is prescribed by Amnesty or any other advocate of abolition of death penalty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imprisonment, for a substantial period of time. There is recognition that the people who are executed are in many cases extremely dangerous to society, and have committed crimes that are heinous and outrageous, and a substantial consequence is demanded. Lengthy (but not indefinite) prison sentences are recommended.

Amnesty and other organisations such as Penal Reform, (linked below) note that some jurisdictions implement "life imprisonment without possibility of parole". But they do not support such sentences.

The UK has "life sentences".  When a judge gives a life sentence, they also impose a "tariff", for the minimum number of years that the prisoner must serve.  At the end of this time the prisoner is eligible for conditional release (subject to review - it's not an automatic right to release), but will be under scrutiny for the remainder of their life, and can be recalled to prison if they break the terms of their release. The UK also has a limited number of prisoners with "whole life tariffs" - for those considered too dangerous, or their crimes too substantial, for them ever to be safely released.

https://www.penalreform.org/resource/alternatives-death-penalty-information-pack/

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware whether *Amnesty International* specify a suggested alternative punishment but the punishment used in the West (where the death penalty is not used) is imprisonment.

Imprisonment can be expensive but crimes which might justify long periods of imprisonment are sufficiently rare for imprisonment to be a viable and humane option.

Comment: Note that at least in the US, inmates on the death penalty are actually more expensive for the government that prisoners on life imprisonment sentences. This happens because prisoners on the death penalty have additional security and more isolation in prison and also spend a least a decade, often several decades in prison before being executed to allow enough time for all possibilities of appeal.